# why does my code crashes when im not saying anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, runtime-error

i have an assistent code that gets input from my mic and do actions depending on what im saying.
for some reason when im not saying anything but there is a background noice (sneeze, cough etc) the type of"actual_result" changes from dict to list, them if im talking again it gets the sentence printing it and then crashes. telling me this error:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

this is the code:

```
import PIL
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import random
import time

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()


def talk(text):
    try:
        print("Assistant - " + text.capitalize())
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()

    except ValueError:
        pass


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            actual_result = listener.recognize_google(voice, show_all=True)
            if actual_result is not None:
                pass
            else:
                take_command()

            if "confidence" in actual_result["alternative"]:
                best_hypothesis = max(actual_result["alternative"],
                                      key=lambda alternative: alternative["confidence"])
            else:
                best_hypothesis = actual_result["alternative"][0]

            # Command is what the user is saying
            command = best_hypothesis["transcript"]
            command = command.lower()
            command = command.replace('alexa', '')
            print("\nUser - " + command.capitalize())
            return command

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

it is reacording until it hears that there is not speach anymore and putting the data into variable called "command", but if there is no speach but any other noise that it detects it crashs, im trying to ignore the whole none sence value that has no speach in it, like a loop that if there is no any word detected then it will keep listning instead of crashing.

Comment: Hi. Could you please give a bit more context, and in particular include the relevant `import` and the definition of `sr`, `listener`?

Comment: Also, if you want to return a value, then you should definitely write `else: return take_command()` instead of `else: take_command()`.

Comment: hii, ill add the entire code, just eddited it :)